# How to add Reality file in a Swift Package Manager?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, arkit, swift-package-manager

I've heard with the Xcode 12 (now in Beta 6), Swift package manager is now able to include resources. But I am not able to open a reality (.rcproject) file.

### Here is what I have tried; (& you can reproduce)

1. I created a new `Augmented Reality App` project. (RealityKit + SwiftUI + Swift)
2. Now if you try to run the project, everything works, you see a default metallic box.
3. Now I created a new `SPM` (Swift package manager)
4. Now I dragged locally created `SPM` to the project and added it to frameworks in General > Targets tab. (To inform the project about locally added spm)
5. I dragged `Experience.rcproject` & `ContentView` (also copied the autogenerated `Experience` enum, you can reach it via Cmd+Click) to `SPM`
6. Fixed some access initializer issue for `ContentView` & added platform support `platforms: [.iOS(.v13)],` in the `SPM`
7. Added `resources` in the `SPM` for the path `Experience.rcproject` exist

After those steps finished I'd except to have an AR included swift package manager. 
But auto generated `Experience` enum throws `.fileNotFound("Experience.reality")` error. 
Seems still not able to find reality file in Bundle?

Have you tried something similar. Waiting any helps. Thanks..

[image: Folder Structure]

*`Package.swift`*

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.3
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "ARSPM",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v13)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "ARSPM",
            targets: ["ARSPM"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "ARSPM",
            dependencies: [], resources: [
                .copy("Resources")
            ]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "ARSPMTests",
            dependencies: ["ARSPM"]),
    ]
)
```

*`ARView.swift`*

```swift
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

public struct EKARView : View {
    public init() { }
    public var body: some View {
        return ARViewContainer().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

public struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    public func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        
        // Load the "Box" scene from the "Experience" Reality File
        let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
        
        // Add the box anchor to the scene
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
        
        return arView
        
    }
    
    public func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
    
}
```

*`GeneratedExperienceFile.swift`*

```swift
//
// Experience.swift
// GENERATED CONTENT. DO NOT EDIT.
//

import Foundation
import RealityKit
import simd
import Combine

internal enum Experience {

    public enum LoadRealityFileError: Error {
        case fileNotFound(String)
    }

    private static var streams = [Combine.AnyCancellable]()

    public static func loadBox() throws -> Experience.Box {
        guard let realityFileURL =
//                Also tried >> Foundation.Bundle.module
                Foundation.Bundle(for: Experience.Box.self)
                    .url(forResource: "Experience", withExtension: "reality") else {
            throw Experience.LoadRealityFileError.fileNotFound("Experience.reality")
        }

        let realityFileSceneURL = realityFileURL.appendingPathComponent("Box", isDirectory: false)
        let anchorEntity = try Experience.Box.loadAnchor(contentsOf: realityFileSceneURL)
        return createBox(from: anchorEntity)
    }

    public static func loadBoxAsync(completion: @escaping (Swift.Result<Experience.Box, Swift.Error>) -> Void) {
        guard let realityFileURL = Foundation.Bundle(for: Experience.Box.self).url(forResource: "Experience", withExtension: "reality") else {
            completion(.failure(Experience.LoadRealityFileError.fileNotFound("Experience.reality")))
            return
        }

        var cancellable: Combine.AnyCancellable?
        let realityFileSceneURL = realityFileURL.appendingPathComponent("Box", isDirectory: false)
        let loadRequest = Experience.Box.loadAnchorAsync(contentsOf: realityFileSceneURL)
        cancellable = loadRequest.sink(receiveCompletion: { loadCompletion in
            if case let .failure(error) = loadCompletion {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
            streams.removeAll { $0 === cancellable }
        }, receiveValue: { entity in
            completion(.success(Experience.createBox(from: entity)))
        })
        cancellable?.store(in: &streams)
    }

    private static func createBox(from anchorEntity: RealityKit.AnchorEntity) -> Experience.Box {
        let box = Experience.Box()
        box.anchoring = anchorEntity.anchoring
        box.addChild(anchorEntity)
        return box
    }

    public class Box: RealityKit.Entity, RealityKit.HasAnchoring {

        public var steelBox: RealityKit.Entity? {
            return self.findEntity(named: "Steel Box")
        }

    }

}
```

And in `ContentView` file, I simple show `EKARView`.

Comment: Can you share your `Package.swift` with the resources references. And any snippets you can share from the `Experience` enum would be helpful.

Comment: @richardpiazza code snippets added.

Comment: A quick look over, the `Bundle` reference to your resources may not be right. When using SPM Resource Bundles, the `Bundle` to use for referencing the resource is `Bundle.module`, instead of `Foundation.Bundle(for: Experience.Box.self)`. Give that a try, if not I'll take another look later.

Comment: Already tried but no luck

Comment: A couple other things to check... Does changing `.copy("Resources")` to `.process("Resources")` alter anything? The URL attempting to be loaded is `Experience.reality` so that would suggest Xcode processes the resource when a part of a project. Is there any command line tools that let you compile the resource and then add it to the Package resources?

Comment: I tried both `copy` and `process` result is same. For second question, actually I build the code (including reality file) in a real project (created in 1st step) then cmd click on `Experience` and went to autogenerated file. After these steps I moved reality file to spm & creted a new file to contain auto generated `Experience enum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode knows how to process a `.rcproject` file into the `.reality` file it needs when building an application. Unfortunately this processing isn't done when accessing the project file using a Swift Package.

The steps you've outlined will almost work. What it comes down to is using the already compiled `.reality` file in place of the `.rcproject` file. In order to transform the default `.rcproject` file, you'll need to use Apple's **Reality Composer** application.

*steps outlined using Xcode 12...*

- With the `Experience.rcproject` file selected, click the 'Open in Reality Composer' button.
- Once open, export the project through the 'File' menu.
- Choose 'Project' and click export. This produces a `Experience.reality` file.
- Place that file in your swift package resources.
- Make sure replace the `Bundle` references in your `Experience.swift` file with `Bundle.module`, as the existing reference will target your application bundle.

Comment: Using exported `reality` file worked, seems everytime we update scene, we need to follow same process for now. :( @richarpiazza
Thanks by the way